# R Shiny Leaflet. Assigning and toggling markers assigned to multiple groups

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create a Shiny app that uses leaflet to display map markers. I want the user to be able to toggle between groups of markers using the UI. With some help from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931602/r-shiny-leaflet-toggle-groups-of-points-from-ui-checkboxgroupinput-as-opposed-to/72938847#72938847), this has been achieved as follows:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("quakesToggle"),
  leafletOutput("mymap",height = '100vh')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data(quakes)
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = quakes) %>% 
      setView(lng = quakes[1, 'long'],
              lat = quakes[1, 'lat'],
              zoom=5) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = quakes[quakes$mag>=5, ],
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       group = 'quakes1',
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = 'red')  %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = quakes[quakes$mag<5, ],
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       group = 'quakes2',
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = 'green')
  })
  
  output$quakesToggle <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('quakesToggle', 'Select magnitude:',
                       choices  = c('Quakes1','Quakes2'),
                       selected = c('Quakes1','Quakes2')
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$quakesToggle, {
    if('Quakes1' %in% input$quakesToggle) {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        showGroup('quakes1')
    } else {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        hideGroup('quakes1')
    }
    
    if('Quakes2' %in% input$quakesToggle) {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        showGroup('quakes2')
    } else {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        hideGroup('quakes2')
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I would like to add additional toggles for the user to select further groups. In this example say `quakes$depth >=350` and also `quakes$depth<350`.

I have achieved rough functionality by extending the list of options in `input$quakesToggle` and adding the additional group designations as new `addCircleMarkers` assignments.

I would prefer to create a new `checkboxGroupInput` for the new groups though. In doing so I create a new `observeEvent` but things start to fall down here given the competing conditions.

I recognise that the problem is that I am attempting to assign points to multiple groups which, if I understand thigs correctly, isn't possible.

How then can I create the functionality required?

Some pointers on how/if this can be achieved would be appreciated!

**Further Elaboration**

The below shows how I already have color assigned to a variable selection, in this instance station (I know this is a silly assignment but it works for the example). Given that color is already assigned as conditional on `input$circle_color`. How then would the filter and grouping that @gdevaux mentions below work?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('quakesToggle'),
  uiOutput('circle_color'),
  leafletOutput("mymap",height = '100vh')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data(quakes)

  output$circle_color <- renderUI({
    selectInput('circle_color', label = 'Variable to colour by:',
                choices = c('stations'), selected = 'stations')
  })
  
  output$quakesToggle <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput('quakesToggle', 'Select magnitude:',
                       choices  = c('Quakes1','Quakes2'),
                       selected = c('Quakes1','Quakes2')
    )
  })
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = quakes) %>% 
      setView(lng = quakes[1, 'long'],
              lat = quakes[1, 'lat'],
              zoom=5) %>%
      addTiles() 
  })
  
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$circle_color)){return('stations')}
    
    colorBy <- input$circle_color
    colorData <- quakes[[input$circle_color]]
    pal1 <- c('green', 'yellow1','orange','red1','purple')
    color <- colorBin(pal1, colorData)
    
    leafletProxy('mymap',data = quakes)%>%
      
      clearShapes() %>%
      
      addCircleMarkers(data = quakes[quakes$mag>=5, ],
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       group = 'quakes1',
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = ~color(colorData)
                       )  %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = quakes[quakes$mag<5, ],
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       group = 'quakes2',
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = ~color(colorData)
      ) %>%
      
      addLegend("topright",
                pal=color,
                values=colorData,
                title=colorBy,
                layerId="colorLegend"
      ) 
  })

  observeEvent(input$quakesToggle, {
    if (is.null(input$circle_color)) {
      return('stations')
    }
    if('Quakes1' %in% input$quakesToggle) {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        showGroup('quakes1')
    } else {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        hideGroup('quakes1')
    }

    if('Quakes2' %in% input$quakesToggle) {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        showGroup('quakes2')
    } else {
      leafletProxy('mymap', data = quakes) %>%
        hideGroup('quakes2')
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution if you want to have multiple filters is to filter your data first, and reload your map every time.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- quakes %>%
  mutate(binary_mag = if_else(mag>=5, 1, 2),
         binary_depth = if_else(depth>=350, 1, 2),
         colorgroup = paste(binary_mag, binary_depth))

mydata$colorgroup[mydata$colorgroup=="1 1"] <- "red"
mydata$colorgroup[mydata$colorgroup=="1 2"] <- "green"
mydata$colorgroup[mydata$colorgroup=="2 1"] <- "blue"
mydata$colorgroup[mydata$colorgroup=="2 2"] <- "yellow"


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("quakesToggle"),
  leafletOutput("mymap",height = '100vh')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Make filters input
  output$quakesToggle <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput('quakesToggleM', 'Select magnitude:',
                         choices  = c('mag>=5','mag<5'),
                         selected = c('mag>=5','mag<5')
      ),
      checkboxGroupInput('quakesToggleD', 'Select depth:',
                         choices  = c('depth>=350','depth<350'),
                         selected = c('depth>=350','depth<350')
      )
    )
  })
  
  # Filter data depending on inputs, you may have to modify here depending on how you want
  # mag and depth inputs to interact (is it mag AND depth ? is it mag OR depth ? etc)
  filtred_data <- eventReactive({
    input$quakesToggleM
    input$quakesToggleD}, {
      res <- mydata %>% {
        if(!is.null(input$quakesToggleM)){
          filter(., eval(parse(text = paste(input$quakesToggleM, collapse = "|"))))
        } else {
          filter(.,TRUE) 
        }
      } %>%{
        if(!is.null(input$quakesToggleD)){
          filter(., eval(parse(text = paste(input$quakesToggleD, collapse = "|"))))
        } else {
          filter(.,TRUE) 
        }
      } 
      if(is.null(input$quakesToggleM) & is.null(input$quakesToggleD)){
        res <- mydata %>% filter(FALSE)
      }
      return(res)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  

  # Make base map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = quakes) %>% 
      setView(lng = quakes[1, 'long'],
              lat = quakes[1, 'lat'],
              zoom=5) %>%
      addTiles()
  })
  
  # Add filtred data markers on map
  observeEvent(filtred_data(), {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
      clearGroup("quakes") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = filtred_data(),
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       group = "quakes",
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = ~colorgroup)
    # add a legend would be great
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And to work with a color input just modify the observeEvent

```
# Add filtred data markers on map
  observeEvent({
    filtred_data()
    input$circle_color
    }, {
    
    colorBy <- input$circle_color
    colorData <- quakes[[input$circle_color]]
    pal1 <- c('green', 'yellow1','orange','red1','purple')
    color <- colorBin(pal1, colorData)
    
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
      clearGroup("quakes") %>%
      removeControl("colorLegend") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = filtred_data(),
                       ~long,
                       ~lat,
                       radius=3,
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       group = "quakes",
                       fillOpacity=0.5,
                       color = ~color(colorData)) %>%
      addLegend("topright",
                pal=color,
                values=colorData,
                title=colorBy,
                layerId="colorLegend"
      ) 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again here! I can see how this solution works. However, I am having difficulty implementing it because I already have marker colour assigned to a UI variable selection and so I'm not sure how to go about the filter process you show as this is later used in the color argument for `addCirclemarkers`. I'll add an updated example to my post so you can see what I'm working with.

Comment: You just need to copy paste your code for the color and add the color input as a trigger for the ObserveEvent, i'll post and update

Comment: and i forgot to replace `colorData <- quakes[[input$circle_color]]` by `colorData <- filtred_data()[[input$circle_color]]`

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this is great. Can I clarify that the filter logic 'and' vs 'or' is determined by the pipe being passed to the  `collapse =` argument in the if statements? So, in your example, if the user has mag<5 and depth<350 selected only points meeting both those condition are displayed? I should be able to adapt this to my use case easily. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, another question if you don't mind. I can see how the logic functions for binary categories in the filter as the number of combinations listed in `mydata$colorgroup` remains small. I assume this would get out of hand quickly if options went beyond binary choices?

Comment: yes I made them by hand because there were few. You can use colorBin (or a derivate like colorFactor) when you have a lot of categories, juste like you did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246376/discussion-between-r0bt-and-gdevaux).